# Firebase isn't initialised on iOS Ionic

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, ionic-framework, cordova-plugin-fcm

I've stumbled onto a problem with my Ionic, Angular, and Firebase app.

I've had this problem before, but it seemed to work itself out, and now I'm having it again, and I'm wondering if anyone knows why.

I'm using Firebase FCM to store a user's `token` to then send them a notification. On android this works perfectly, and on iOS it used to work..

I generated my `GoogleService-Info.plist` file from Firebase and put it in my main folder.

I have the following code to get the `fcm` token:

```
 getFCMToken() {
    let token;
    this.firebaseNative.getToken().then((tok) => {
        token = tok;
        if(this.platform.is('ios')) {
          this.firebaseNative.grantPermission().then((tok) => {
            return this.fcmToFirestore(token);
          }).catch(error => this.showToast("There was an error: " + error));
        } else {
          return this.fcmToFirestore(token);
        }
    }).catch(error => {
        this.showToast("There was an error: " + error)
    });
  }

  fcmToFirestore(token) {
    if (!token) return;

    const devicesRef = this.afs.collection('devices')
    const docData = {
      token,
      userId: this.userData.uid,
    }
    return devicesRef.doc(token).set(docData);
  }
```

When I run the following code on an iPhone I get the toast message:

> There was an error: Firebase isn't initialised

I initialize the app in `app.module.ts` in the `imports`, which has always worked, and as I said, works fine on android.

Any idea why this doesn't work on iOS? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is an issue with the installed version of firebase plugin.

I mitigated this error by downgrading to 1.0.5

```
cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-firebase
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase@1.0.5 --save
```

P.S. Make sure `config.xml` has firebase mentioned with the required version. This helps to keep versions same across all the development systems.

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-firebase" spec="~1.0.5" />
```

Comment: I'm unfortunately already on `1.0.5`: `<plugin name="cordova-plugin-firebase" spec="^1.0.5" />`, I'm not sure if the `^` makes a difference?

Comment: There were some different errors in 1.0.5, i further downgraded to `0.1.18`. Check if this works for you. I have updated my answer so you can check it if it works :)

Comment: thanks for the tip! I'll try it and report back! Is downgrading so far a good idea?

Comment: Unfortunately, downgrading is the only option when backward compatibility breaks with frequent releases.

Comment: Worked like a charm! `1.0.5` was the one for me.

Answer (score 0):

`FCM` is `Firebase Cloud Messaging`, which barely supports the readability (this is a whole other product than `Firestore`). the `CocoaPods` might lack relevant dependency, which would explain it not being known to `.ts` on iOS. comparing the current version of the `CocoaPods` with a previous version should show what exactly changed there (a good reason to use version control).

see the [FirebaseFirestore Framework Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes) ...this has nothing to do with JavaScript.

this here would be the one required: [pods/FirebaseFirestore](https://cocoapods.org/pods/FirebaseFirestore).

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following. So what would I need to do to get this to start working again? I need to get the FCM token from a user to be able to push the notification

Answer (score 0):

[EDIT]

Note that since `cordova-plugin-firebase` version 2.x the `initXXXXX`-methods have been removed again.

And version 1.1.x has been marked as `deprecated`.

[/EDIT]

---

First, it would be helpful, if you could provide some more details of the libraries/versions you are using.

I guess you are using `cordova-plugin-firebase` version 1.1.x in combination with `@ionic-native/firebase` (?)

It seems, `cordova-plugin-firebase` has some new initialization-methods that need to be explicitly invoked now, before you can use firebase services.

Namely

```
FirebasePlugin.initFirebase(success, error)

FirebasePlugin.initAnalytics(success, error)
FirebasePlugin.initCrashlytics(success, error)
FirebasePlugin.initPerformance(success, error)
FirebasePlugin.initRemoteConfig(success, error)
```

Note that the latest version of `@ionic-native/firebase` as of now (v4.12.2) does not yet has these functions integrated yet.

So for using these in an Ionic app you may need, to access the "raw" `FirebasePlugin` instance itself like

```
declare var FirebasePlugin;
// ...
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
  FirebasePlugin.initFirebase(...
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the problem is that Firebase now starts uninitialized, and requires a function to be called for this purpose, before your code calls getToken().

The bit of code you need is `(<any>window).FirebasePlugin.initFirebase()`

I've been able to get this info from the github of the cordova firebase plugin, where other people were having the same problem. For some reason though google didn't find this, perhaps it's too new of a problem still

https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase/issues/816